# Finding an analytical solution to a simple 2D Finite Element Method problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJkE.jpg)

Is it possible to find the value of scalar function u(x, y) anywhere in the region $\Omega$, given the following:

$\nabla \cdot$ ($\nabla$u) = f,

u(x,y) = g when y = 0, L$_2$

($\nabla$u)$_x$ = h when x = 0, L$_1$

where f, g and h are given scalar valued functions

I ask because it is possible to solve the equivalent 1D problem:

$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$ = f,

u(0) = g$_1$,

$\frac{du}{dx}$ = g$_2$ when x = L

by stating: u(x) = g$_1$ + $\int_0^x\bigl(-\int_x^L$f dx  + g$_2\bigl)$ dx.

And both the 1D and 2D problems are solvable using the finite element method. But I can’t figure out a way on paper to derive u(x,y).

I tried reasoning:

u(x,y) = u(x,0) + $\int_0^y$ ($\nabla$u)$_y$ dy.

where ($\nabla$u)$_y$ = ($\nabla$u(x,0))$_y$ + $\int_0^y \frac{\delta ^2u}{\delta y^2} $ dy.

But ($\nabla$u(x,0))$_y$ and $\frac{\delta ^2u}{\delta y^2}$ are unknown so I can’t get any further.

Alternatively, using the divergence theorem:

$\int_{\Omega_0}$ f dA = -$\int_{L_a}^{L_b}$ ($\nabla$u(0,y))$_x$ dy + $\int_0^{L_1}$ ($\nabla$u(x,$L_b$))$_y$ dx + $\int_{L_a}^{L_b}$ ($\nabla$u($L_1$,y))$_x$ dy - $\int_0^{L_1}$ ($\nabla$u(x,$L_a$))$_y$ dx.

Where $L_a$ and $L_b$ are two values of y between 0 and $L_2$ and $\Omega_0$ is the rectangular region bounded by 0 and $L_1$ on the x axis and $L_a$ and $L_b$ on the y axis.

So $\int_0^{L_1}$ ($\nabla$u(x,$L_b$))$_y$ dx - $\int_0^{L_1}$ ($\nabla$u(x,$L_a$))$_y$ dx = A.

where A = $\int_\Omega$ f dA + $\int_{L_a}^{L_b}$ ($\nabla$u(0,y))$_x$ dy - $\int_{L_a}^{L_b}$ ($\nabla$u($L_1$,y))$_x$ dy.

Therefore ($\nabla$u(x,$L_b$))$_y$ - ($\nabla$u(x,$L_a$))$_y$ = $\frac{\delta A}{\delta x}$,

but there are parts of A for which we don’t know $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}$.

So my question is, am I missing something and it’s possible to find u(x,y) or is there not enough information?

Many thanks and sorry it’s so long winded.

Comment: are you asking how to solve poissons equation for a rectangle? It looks like you're using green's functions?

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/yzheng/m597k/m597kLVI8.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link Ryan, it looks interesting. I will look through it. I just wanted to know whether there was a simple way of expressing u() given the starting information. Seems like it is a broader problem than I realised!

Comment: It turns out to looking fairly simply if you have only $1$ side that isn't $0$.   Then you use the same method for all the sides like that. I think that's what you meant.

Comment: Would the solution in your link apply to that case? As it assumes that u is 0 along all the sides. The original problem that I came across is this: https://open.umich.edu/sites/default/files/downloads/codingAssign2.pdf. More than two sides have non zero value here.

Comment: if it is $0$ on all sides you'd have sine and cosines for eigenfunctions

Comment: your other boundary is neumann

Comment: when they are not homogeneous you end up with something different..I'll post something tomorrow..

Comment: i attempted the problem and I think they're saying only the top and bottom are non-zero and I can't tell from notation. it says $\kappa= 385$ which is joules I would figure they're dirichlet...The numbers 310 likely come from the discretization. the mesh is $15 \times 40 =600$

Comment: the problem says to find the steady state..which is reference temperature..if you solve the heat equation and $t \to \infty$ then $u(x,t) \to 0$ for the homogeneous case. which means the non-homogeneous parts are what is left or $r(x,y)$

Comment: that means you have should have $\sum_{i=1}^{4} \nabla^{2} r_{i} $

Answer (score 1):

### In your problem

We get two problems

$$ \nabla^{2}u =0  \tag{1}$$

on a rectangle with $ x \in [0,0.3]$ and $ y\in [0.8] $ subject to the boundaries 
$$ \textrm{ Left }  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y)  = 0  \\  \textrm{ Right } \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0.3,y) = 0 \\ $$
$$ \textrm{Bottom }  u(x,0) =A(x) \\  \textrm{ Top } u(x,0.8) = B(x) $$

in the end it is a function of $x,y$ and we solve the bottom.

$$ u(x,y) = v(x,y) + r(x,y) \tag{2} $$

$$ r(x,0) = A(x) = 300(1+\frac{x}{3}) \tag{3} $$
$$ r(x,0.8) = B(x) = 310(1+8x^{2}) \tag{4}  $$

$$ \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}r(x,0) =  0 \tag{5} $$
$$ \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}r(x,.8) =  4960 \tag{6} $$

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the detailed reply and sorry for my late response. I’ve tried to work through my particular problem using your approach above, but still have some questions:

Comment: I think in my case, the first line: $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla^{2}u +  Q(x,y)  \tag{1}$$ reduces to $$\nabla^{2}u = 0$$ as it’s a steady state problem and **f** is 0 (we were told this somewhere else in the assignment, I forgot to mention it)

Comment: The next step is the Dirichlet boundaries. Mine are in terms of x, rather than t: $$u(x,0)  = A(x)  \\  u(x,H) = B(x) \\ A(x) = 300(1 + \frac{1}{3}x) \\ B(x) = 310(1 + 8x^2)$$ so I’m not sure how to proceed here...

Comment: your boundaries $u(x,0)$ are a function of $x$ but are actually along the $0 \leq y \leq H $ boundary...

Comment: I think in my case the Dirichlet boundaries are along the top & bottom horizontal sides of the rectangle?

Comment: I don't know if that works.

Comment: So it would seem that in simple cases with constant dirichlet/Neumann boundaries, u() can be found using the Eigenvalue problem, but when there’s a more complicated expression along some boundaries, there may not be a solution? I have learnt a lot here anyway, thank you for taking the time :)

Comment: well it should be $0$ everywhere else and something like $5000$ at the top boundary.