# To solve a PDE using Separation of Variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Would it be possible for someone to guide me through this problem.

The PDE is,
$\Delta u =0$

We have the following boundary solutions: where a and b are real numbers
u(0,y)=c1, 
u(a,y)=c1, 
u(x,0)=g(x), $\frac{\delta u}{\delta v}$(x,b)=c2
where c1 and c2 are real numbers.

I have to solve this for x in [0,a] and y in [0,b]

Could someone help me out for this problem. I'm beginner at PDE. I was able to break up the problem to $V^{II}=\lambda V$ and  $W^{II}=-\lambda W$. I know that I have to break it up and solve 4 PDEs.

For u(0,y)=c1, and all the other boundary's zero, I found $\lambda > 0$.
For u(a,y)=c1, and all the other boundary's zero, I also found $\lambda > 0$. For the last 2 solutions I found $\lambda<0$.

I think the v in $\frac{\delta u}{\delta v}$(x,b)=c2 is the outward pointing normal vector and I believe it should equal y except I can't figure out why.

I've spent hours on the problem trying to work out the solutions and I can't seem to get anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplacesEqn.aspx

Comment: @RyanHowe, thank you! I've actually already looked through his notes and I can't seem to find anything about an outward pointing normal vector as part of the boundaries!

Comment: one moment...i'll walk through it.

Comment: Subtract $c_1$ from $u$ to obtain $v=u-c_1$ where $v(0,y)=0$, $v(a,y)=0$ and $\Delta v = 0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts sorry, I'm a little confused on why you would do this! thank you!

Comment: Separation of variables problems result in eigenfunction problems only in the variables where you have two homogeneous endpoint conditions. The last direction is solved in a different way.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953314/finding-an-analytical-solution-to-a-simple-2d-finite-element-method-problem/2955539#2955539 this is an example I did a few days ago..

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=u-c_1$. The problem for $v$ is
$$
      \Delta v = 0 \\
    v(0,y)=0,\;\; v(a,y)=0\\
    v(x,0)=g(x)-c_1,\;\; v_y(x,b)=c_2.
$$
This problem is the sum of solutions of the following two problems
$$     \Delta v = 0 \\
    v(0,y)=0,\;\; v(a,y)=0\\
    v(x,0)=g(x)-c_1,\;\; v_y(x,b)=0.
$$
$$     \Delta v = 0 \\
    v(0,y)=0,\;\; v(a,y)=0\\
    v(x,0)=0,\;\; v_y(x,b)=c_2.
$$
Then $u=v+c_1$ is the desired solution.